# What are the pros and cons of use webpack templates to create a vue project

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, bundle, webpack-2

I learned vue.js through a tutorial there, I learned to create a vue project using

```
vue init webpack-simple my-project
```

then install node modules and run using

```
npm run dev
```

Then I have found another way

```
vue create my-project
```

run using

```
npm run serve
```

Are there any other ways to create a vue project **other than these two**?
Why we should / should not use web-pack templates to create vue projects?

Comment: vue create uses the recent version of the vue-cli (v3), vue init is outdated. You should use create instead. Note that create also creates a webpack project for you.

Comment: But I'm unable to find my webpack.config.js file now.

Comment: Because there is none now as it's handled by vues standard configuration. You can still alter though, this post might be helpful for your understanding https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2018/03/26/vue-cli-3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also manually call vueJs like you'd call jquery without using a module bundler which should work fine.

```
<script src="vue.js"></script>
<script>
  // Your vue code
</script>
```

If you're building a complex application webpack helps you to easily manage you javascript files without having to call each file manually in your html.

If your application is fairly small, and you don't have many static assets and you only need to build one Javascript file to serve to the client, then Webpack might be more than you need.